# Исправить коллизии в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Опишу проблему: каждый кадр идёт проверка игрока на столкновение с стеной с помощью `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` , но иногда, например, когда фпс ниже 10 и проверка идёт реже может быть такое, что игрок просто пройдёт через стену не "попав" в неё.
Можно ли как-нибудь улучшить проверку коллизий, убрав данную проблему?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Кусок кода в `player.update()`: Решаю в лоб.

```
if player.rect.left < 0: print('Коллизия')
if player.rect.right > WIDTH: print('Коллизия')
if player.rect.top < 0: print('Коллизия')
if player.rect.bottom > HEIGHT: print('Коллизия')
```

`WIDTH` и `HEIGHT` - Это константы - ширина и высота окошка программы соостветсвенно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять вектор передвижения игрока и если персонаж сталкивается со стеной, просто вычесть из его координат тот вектор